# Explanation of "Another Advantage of Free Choice: Completely Asynchronous Agreement Protocols"

Tags: distributed-system, consensus, paxos, raft

Can anyone, please, clarify step 3 (see below) in the "[Completely Asynchronous Agreement Protocol](https://allquantor.at/blockchainbib/pdf/ben1983another.pdf)":

Process P: Initial value xp.

- **Step 0**: set `r := 1`.
- **Step 1**: Send the message `(1, r, xp)` to all the processes.
- **Step 2**: Wait till `N - t` messages of type `(1, r, x)`, are received. If more than `N/2` messages have the same value `v`, then send the message `(2, r, v, D)` to all processes. Else send the message `(2, r, ?)` to all processes.
- **Step 3**: Wait till `N - t` messages of type `(2, r)` arrive.

  - (a) If there is one D-message `(2, r, v, D)` then set `xp := v`.
  - (b) If there are more than `t` D-messages, then decide `v`.
  - (c) Else set `xp = 1` or `0` each with probability 1/2.
- **Step 4**: Set `r := r + 1` and go to step 1.

I understand this protocol as follows.

At the first step each node notifies every other node about its state.

At the second step each node decides whether it has "seen" enough information to determine the value or not, in other words it waits for majority. If majority has the same value, it starts broadcasting this information, like "I saw that majority thinks `v`". Otherwise it sends message that it did not make up its mind.

Finally, in the third step, we check if we have more than `t` "decisive" messages (in case if messages of `t` nodes will not be delivered there will be at least one "decisive" message). But I do not understand why we set `xp := v` only if we receive **exactly one** D-message. Receiving two D-messages falls into 3c, in which case we are going to assign random value to v. Why?

Why can not we describe the third step like:

- (a) If there is zero D-message then set `xp = 1` or `0` each with probability 1/2.
- (b) If there are more than `t` D-messages, then decide `v`.
- (c) Else set `xp := v`.

Answer (score 0):

The paper you linked introduces the Ben-Or consensus algorithm. It provides two versions of it, one for simple probabilistic consensus and one for byzantine agreement. The pseudo-code you provided reproduces the former.

Notice that the meaning of step **3 (a)** can be a bit misleading:

```
If there is one D-message (2, r, v, D) then set xp := v
```

It doesn't mean "exactly one", rather "at least one". This can be inferred from the [1998 algorithm's correctness proof](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/7336/98-1682.pdf?sequence=1) in which the third step is slightly rephrased:

```
wait for messages of the form (P, k, ∗) from n − f processes {“∗” can be 0, 1 or ?}
if received at least f + 1 (P, k, v) with the same v != ? then decide(v)
if at least one (P, k, v) with v != ? then x ← v else x ← 0 or 1 randomly {query r.n.g.}
```